# Find triangles to fill rectangle

Tags: geometry

I'm looking to solve the following problem:

Given a rectangle R and a shape S within that rectangle, find all shapes that, if combined with S, would fill R (without overlapping). The shapes are give by a set of points that make up the path around that shape.

This is probably a fairly common problem in computer graphics but I couldn't find anything when googling this.

If it makes things easier the shapes could all be triangles.

Comment: What do you have in mind when you are talking about shapes? The minimal number of shapes that fill the empty space is one. It is the shape that has the same boundary as the rectangle and $S$. However, $S$ might be extremly complictaed, e.g. holes, not connected. If you want to use only triangles you must triangulate this one shape but there are infinitely many solutions

Comment: For some tiles the tiling problem is NP hard. If you want a solution in sensible time you might need to sacrifice some generality.

Comment: Maybe check out [Polygon triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation).

Comment: It is not at all clear to me what you are after, even if we stick to triangles. Are wanting just *some* triangulation of the rectangle having $S$ as one of the triangles? The way you asked the question sounds like you want every possible such triangulation, but that is an impossible task as there are infinitely many of them (even more of them than you can index with integers). If you want just one triangulation, are there any other requirements than $S$ being among them? Because if that is the only requirement, the problem is almost trivial.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair No additional requirements, just one set of triangles that fills the remaining rectangle. I guess I can figure out how to do it for triangles, but I was hoping there was a generic solution for all kinds of polygons. If there is a standard algorithm for doing this (with triangles) I'd still be interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are uncountably many ways of dividing the region between a rectangle $R$ and an interior polygon $S$. Since you are representing polygons as a sequence of vertices, you probably want a simply-connected polygon (no holes) so that there is a single border.

The simplest method to get this is to just draw a line segment from some point on $S$ to some point on the boundary $R$, in a direction that doesn't intersect $S$ again:

[image]

This converts $R\setminus S$ into a single polygon, with boundary $(a,b,c,d,a,e,f,g,h,i,e,a)$. Note that this polygon borders itself, including the line segment $\overline{ae}$ twice in its boundary. For many applications, this is not a problem. But if it is, you can always add a second cut line, for example from $b$ to a point $j$ on $\overline{hi}$. That divides $R\setminus S$ into two polygons: $(a,d,c,b,j,h,g,f,e,a)$ and $(a,b,j,i,e,a)$.

If your polygons need to be convex, then perhaps the most straightforward approach is to simply extend the sides of $S$ until they intersect $R$. This works even if $S$ itself is not convex. Ignore where the lines lay inside $S$, but cut up $R\setminus S$ along the lines to get convex polygons.

[image]